# get the minimum of a column value based on other columns value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

am trying to fetch the whole row's based on minimum value of a column with coditions

Df :

```
colA    colB    colC
    A   B   2
    B   C   3
    C   D   4
    D   E   5
    E   A   2
    A   A   0
    B   B   0
    C   C   0
    D   D   0
    E   E   0
```

trying to fetch the whole row where the colC is minimum integer but where as the colA and colB is not equal in the fastest way

output:

```
A   B   2
E   A   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out first not same columns, then sorting and get lowest 2 values:

```
df1 = df[df['colA'].ne(df['colB'])].sort_values('colC').head(2)
```

And for all another rows remove rows by index from original:

```
df2 = df.drop(df1.index)

print (df1)
  colA colB  colC
0    A    B     2
4    E    A     2

print (df2)
  colA colB  colC
1    B    C     3
2    C    D     4
3    D    E     5
5    A    A     0
6    B    B     0
7    C    C     0
8    D    D     0
9    E    E     0
```

Comment: can we do this using numpy ?

Comment: @pylearner - hmmm, there are stings with integers columns, so more complicated. DataFrame is very large?

Comment: yea the df is very large

Comment: @pylearner - Can you test solution now? `df1` is 2 minimal, `df2` are another values.

Comment: can I add multiple constraints in .ne ??

Comment: @pylearner - Do you need test multiple columns if not equal?

Comment: I want to include another condition in .ne(), 
`ex: df['colB'] shouldnt contain 'E'`

Comment: @pylearner - then add next condition `df['colA'].ne(df['colB'])` to `df['colA'].ne(df['colB']) & df['colB'].ne('E')`